# Horizontal scaling for scheduled task

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, microservices

There is a service (microservice in spring-boot):

- the service has a scheduled task (task1), which searches the database (mongodb) for tasks with state = READY and processes those tasks
- state = READY tasks are assigned according to the schedule in a separate scheduled task (task2)

What we need:

- rework the service for the horizontal scaling (is there best practiсe?)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a message-queue that holds the tasks with state = ready. The service which adds/updates the task into DB, pushes an event on a message queue (you can use RabbitMQ, SQS, Azure Service Bus - it depends on your cloud provider / preference)

You can even create a dedicated service which periodically searches for tasks with state = READY and adds them into the queue.

Then, you can have a dedicated microservice which listen on that queue, and processes incoming events. This one is horizontally scalable, each replica will pick a different event from the queue, so the throughput is increased.